# asp.net set value of attribute with a namespace prefix. (xlink:href on svg/use element)

Tags: c#, asp.net, svg, webforms, xlink

I'm attempting to place `svg` in my page with an external reference by using a `use` element as shown below:

```
<svg class="xyz" width="25px" height="25px" fill="red" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <use id="useLogo" runat=server class="xyz" href="~/Content/images/test.svg#shape" xlink:href="~/Content/images/test.svg#shape"></use>
</svg>
```

The issue is that I'm doing this in a user control, and so I need to reference the `svg` file relative to the application, not the page that the user control is on.

I decided to use the `~` character in the `href` and `xlink:href` attributes, then on `page_load`:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    this.useLogo.Attributes["href"] = Page.ResolveUrl(this.useLogo.Attributes["href"]);
    //this.useLogo.Attributes["xlink:href"] = Page.ResolveUrl(this.useLogo.Attributes["xlink:href"]);
}
```

This does work, but for backwards compatibility, I need to do the same thing with the `xlink:href` attribute. The namespace appears to be tripping up ASP.Net as the `AttributeCollection` of the element does not have an item for that attribute. Is there some way to recognized namespaced attributes, or is there a totally different way to do this?

Comment: "this" is the Page - you're looking at the Page_Load event of an aspx page.  So the useLogo object is the "use" element on the page.

Comment: The issue is the "xlink:href" does not appear in the list of attributes in the  element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run your application in the browser and view the source, you will notice that the `xlink:href` was stripped out and your control is rendered as:

```
<use id="MainContent_useLogo" class="xyz" href="~/Content/images/test.svg#shape"></use>
```

Notice that the `runat` attribute is missing too. All of that is the result of processing the tag by the ASP engine, which decides what to do with each attribute.

Because those two attributes are stripped out, the `Attributes` properties doesn't include them and it only includes the `class` and `href` in your case.

Since you want the `href` and `xlink:href` attributes to have the same value, you can simply add the `xlink:href` attribute programmatically and set it to the value of the `href` attribute:

```
useLogo.Attributes["href"] = ResolveUrl(this.useLogo.Attributes["href"]);
useLogo.Attributes.Add("xlink:href", useLogo.Attributes["href"]);
```